# Ruby: mysql throws error when using set function

Tags: mysql, ruby

I do access a mysql database via mysql2 gem.

`conn.query("SET @showcurrent := false; SELECT * from admins;"`)

throws me an error:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * from admins' at line 1
```

if I exclude set function it works. How can I make it work with a `set` function?

`conn.query("SELECT * from admins;"`)

```
=> #<Mysql2::Result:0x00ff8557af200 @query_options={:as=>:hash, :async=>false, :cast_booleans=>false, :symbolize_keys=>false, :database_timezone=>:local, :application_timezone=>nil, :cache_rows=>true, :connect_flags=>bla, :cast=>true, :default_file=>nil, :default_group=>nil, :host=>"bla1", :username=>"bla", :password=>"bla", :database=>"bla", :port=>3007}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
conn.query("SET @showcurrent = false; SELECT * from admins;")
```

Comment: does not work. shows an error: `Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * from admins' at line 1`

Comment: How about this: `conn.query("SELECT *,@showcurrent:=false from admins;")`

Comment: Well, if I do it, the @showcurrent will not be set, so whenever I use it in the query afterwards it is not evaluated. The idea of set is that you assign some specific value to this variable and access it later.

Comment: Okay so the core of the problem is that you cannot run multiple statements using query. You could try running two consecutive queries:
`conn.query("SET @showcurrent = false;")
conn.query("SELECT * from admins;")`
But i'm not sure @showcurrent will carry on to multiple statements in this situation either.